# Is it possible to detect if cookie is enabled on client on ASP.NET server side?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to detect if cookie is enabled on client on ASP.NET server side? Can such info be obtained from the **HttpRequest** object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to determine if cookies are enabled in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210321/best-way-to-determine-if-cookies-are-enabled-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get such information from HttpRequest.What you have to do is write a cookie first and then try to read it again. If you could able to read it then it means it will accept cookies or else it wont. For more info: **“[Determining Whether a Browser Accepts Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)”**.